# Is ham safe to eat if it was at room temperature but is recooked?

Tags: storage, ham

I accidentally left two half hams in a storage locker in a basement for four days. They were in packaged in plastic and packed in ice, but the ice would have melted by the end of the second day. They were at room temperature when I found them. The hams were from a grocer, sealed in plastic. One is semi-cooked. The other is fully cooked, smoked and salted. Are they safe to eat if I cook them to 160 degrees + or, as I suspect, do they need to be thrown out?

Comment: Grocery store hams are not sufficiently cured to be kept at room temperature, and this is well over the 2-4 hour maximum guideline.  YOu should discard these hams.

Comment: If it's a country ham (so heavily salted that you need to soak to make it edible again), it'd be fine ... but that likely wouldn't have been chilled to start with.